# Open a WPF Window in Custom command VSIX

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, vsix

I want to developp a Visual Studio(2015)  extension that simply creates a WPF windows in which I can read or edit file Content (yaml extension)

```
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", this.GetType().FullName);
        string title = "EditFluxCommand";



        //var selectedItems = ((UIHierarchy)((DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE))).Windows.Item("{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}").Object).SelectedItems as object[];


        var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
        if (dte.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) return;

        foreach (SelectedItem selectedItem in dte.SelectedItems)
        {

            if (selectedItem.ProjectItem == null) return;
            var projectItem = selectedItem.ProjectItem;
            var fullPathProperty = projectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath");
            if (fullPathProperty == null) return;
            var fullPath = fullPathProperty.Value.ToString();

            //var mywindow = new EditFlux();


            //Show a message box to prove we were here
            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                this.ServiceProvider,
                fullPath,
                title,
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it dos not Work... Anyone can hELP

Comment: you tried what ? var mywindow = new EditFlux(); and then ? mywindow.ShowDialog(); ?

Comment: Yes But it dos not work No window is open

Comment: has you are in a "hosted" env/application, perhaps you need to give a parent window; see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943166.aspx

Comment: and this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915831/open-custom-user-control-in-tool-window-using-vs-package ==> extend toolpanel ??

Comment: I check this exampble but my window is not a modal !!!

Comment: I  really am lost

Comment: I am checking ...